# How to run only a single command in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, alias, dot-files

I want to execute a single command with .bashrc or dotfile support.
For eg: Opening Firefox browser by typing `firefox`.
I don't want to open terminal, then execute the command  and then exit the terminal.

I have tried KRunner but it is very limiting in functionality as I cannot use aliases or functions defined in dotfiles.

Comment: This is unclear. Is the user logging in through the console or through an ssh connection? Is ssh tunneling assumed? Will `ForceCommand` for user `foo` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` work as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713680/ssh-force-command-execution-on-login-even-without-shell)?

Comment: I am using my local machine. I have logged using sddm display manager.

Comment: Is Alt + F2 what you are looking for?

Comment: It opens up the KRunner. It is good but it doesn't see the aliases defined in .bashrc or any   dotfile